# Lua: <expression> expected near 'do'

Tags: arrays, split, lua, expression, lua-table

My project is to create a script that can let user open multiple folder at once, and the user can type the path that they want to create their folders in.
This is the part of the code that cause me problems.

```lua
List_length = #Filename

List_next = 1

function Main(Filename)
    for List_next, List_length, List_next in
        do os.execute("mkdir " .. Folderpath.. Slash .. Filename)
        List_next = List_next + 1
    end
        SuscessMSG()
    end

Main(Filename)
```

Problem:

```
Lua: <expression> expected near 'do'
```

I have no idea what is the problem, I have watched the documentation of Lua about expression, and I still don't understand how to solve this error.

Can someone please help me? thank you.

Comment: Watch document again, the for syntax is `for a,b,c in explist do block end` or `for v = a,b,c do block end`

Comment: [Full Code](https://pastebin.com/7venJcZx)

Answer (score 1):

This

```
for List_next, List_length, List_next in
        do os.execute("mkdir " .. Folderpath.. Slash .. Filename)
        List_next = List_next + 1
    end
```

Is no valid Lua code.

You're missing an expression list between `in` and `do`.

Also here:

```
Filename = Split(Input_filename, Sep)
 
Filename = io.read("*l")
```

You're assigning a table followed by a string to the same variable. Which will cause further problems.

Assuming a list of strings `t` you can simply iterate over the elements using

```
for _, str in ipairs(t) do
    print(str)
end
```